# How to extract data from a .list file with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I have a .list file containing information on movies. The file is formatted as follows

```
New  Distribution  Votes  Rank  Title
      0000000125  1176527   9.2  The Shawshank Redemption (1994)
      0000000125  817264   9.2  The Godfather (1972)
      0000000124  538216   9.0  The Godfather: Part II (1974)
      0000000124  1142277   8.9  The Dark Knight (2008)
      0000000124  906356   8.9  Pulp Fiction (1994)
```

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
//modules ill be using
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('csv');

csv().from.path('files/info.txt', { delimiter: '  '})
.to.array(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

But because the values are separated by single spaces, double spaces and tabs. There is no single delimiter to use. How can I extract this information into an array?

Comment: This list file is auto-generated or, you have manualy created it?

Comment: auto generated, its the imdb one found ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/pub/misc/movies/database/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shrink multiple spaces in to one space with and then you can read it as string like;

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('files/info.txt', 'utf8', function (err, csvdata) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  var movies = csvdata.replace(/\s+/g, "\t");

  csv().from.string(moviews, { delimiter: '\t'})
    .to.array(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });

});
```

Comment: I think multiple spaces to one tab will be better, otherwise "The Shawshank Redemption (1994)" will be parsed as four fields.

Comment: I decided to separate with commas on two or more spaces data.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ",") - thanks for the response :)

Comment: Good to hear that, an upvote would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks easy to parse with regex:

```
function parse(row) {
  var match = row.match(/\s{6}(\d*)\s{2}(\d*)\s{3}(\d*\.\d)/)
  return {
    distribution: match[1],
    votes: match[2],
    rank: match[3]
  };
}

fs.readFileSync(file)
  .split('\n')
  .slice(1) //since we don't care about the first row
  .map(parse);
```

I will live you to build the rest of the regex. I juse two tools to do so: rubular.com and node.js repl.

This `\s{6}(\d*)\s{2}(\d*)` means: MATCH 6 SPACEs, then capture an arbitrary number of digits then match 2 spaces, then capture another arbitrary number of digits, etc.